# How to display Voice Recognition Settings screen programmatically

Tags: android, voice-recognition

From within an Android app, how to show the system Voice Recognition Settings screen?

Note: there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868410/how-to-show-up-the-google-voice-recognition-settings-in-my-app) but it is out of date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre-Jelly Bean, the way to do this is using the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.voicesearch", "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences");
```

HOWEVER: I have not had a chance to test this on Honeycomb (API 11-13) - anyone know?

Jelly Bean, you need to change the package name:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences");
```