# Which library contains `com.google.android.voicesearch.DetailsReceiver` nowadays?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-voice-search

I finally migrated an old project of mine from Eclipse/ADT to Android Studio (2021.3.1.17).

In the course of this migration, I fixed numerous issues stemming from outdated and deprecated methods and keywords that used to work perfectly on Android 2.2 (API 8) and did not produce any warnings on Eclipse/ADT.

But now, on Android Studio 2021.3, target SDK 33, I am getting this error in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
Class referenced in the manifest, 
`com.google.android.voicesearch.DetailsReceiver`, 
was not found in the project or the libraries
```

I combed Google for clues on how to fix this but apparently this `DetailsReceiver` is so old that there really is no reference to it anymore.

How do eliminate this error in Android Studio?
Is there a reference I can add to the module to make it go away?

**Update:** The package that **used to** include this `DetailsReceiver` used be downloadable from `market://details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch`. It no longer exists on Google Play.

If you search Google Play for `com.google.android.voicesearch` you will get the following matches associated with Google LLC:

1. Google Assistant
2. Google Assistant Go
3. Google
4. Google Access
5. Google Go
6. Assistant
7. I may have missed one...

I am confused. So many candidates for a direct replacement of `com.google.android.voicesearch` but unclear documentation or information about this. Which **downloadable** package replaced it?

I am emphasizing "downloadable" because, on an out-of-box Google Pixel 4a (Android 11), `PackagManager` cannot find `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` when queried.

The closest clue I have been able to find is in this SO thread: [how to show up the google voice recognition settings in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868410/how-to-show-up-the-google-voice-recognition-settings-in-my-app)

But I need a definitive clearer answer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 separate issue related to the [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer):

**Issue 1:**
PackagManager's inability to find `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` when queried is due to [a new requirement starting from Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776190/2597758) (API 30) and higher to explicitly specify [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

---

**Issue 2:** What replaced `market://details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch` is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (AKA `Google`, #3 in the OP question).

It is listed among the components in:

1. SO answer to [How to to display SpeechRecognizer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34738985/2597758) and
2. SO answer to [SpeechRecognizer not available when targeting Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64331678/2597758).

It is still unclear when exactly the `Google` app replaced the `Google Voice Search` app, but among my devices, this appears to be as early as in Android 8.1. So, this could be earlier.

Googling `"voicesearch" replaced by "googlequicksearchbox" site:google.com` reveals quite a few matches but no official announcement per se. Yet, some claim that the package `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` was first introduced in Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) which was released in June 2012.